# Open up new files in Visual Studio 2008 and having tabs go from left to right

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to tweak Visual Studio 2008 so that new files are opened so they are "tabbed up" beginning from left and adding new tabs to the right?

As it is default tabs are added to the left.

Answer (score 1):

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623540/changing-visual-studio-2008-new-tab-position

Note, it's a paid add-in, so may or may not be suitable for you.